# Does Gauss Seidel converge in a finite number of steps

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

> Consider the matrix $$A = \begin{pmatrix}
> 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
> 1 & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
> 0 & 0 & 5 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
> 1 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 0 & 0\\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5 & 1\\
> 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5\\
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>   Does Gauss-Seidel converge in a finite number of steps when solving $A x = b$ for all $b$ and $x_0$?

We have from Gauss-Seidel the matrix
 $$G_{gs} = (D - L)^{-1}U = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0.2 & 0 & 0.2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Since the spectral radius is less than $1$ i.e. $\rho(G_{gs}) < 1$ Gauss-Seidel converges.

Does this imply that Gauss-Seidel converges in a finite number of steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gauss-Seidel has two matrices involved in the iteration process: a (nonstrictly) lower triangular matrix $L$ and $G=L^{-1}U$ where $U$ is a strictly upper triangular matrix. (This is slightly different from your notation.) You can untangle the recursion to find that $x_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k G^k L^{-1}b + (-1)^n G^n x_0$.

If there is some $n$ such that $G^n=0$, then $x_{n+1}=x_n$ and so by induction the sequence stays constant thereafter. Does this happen in your case?

Comment: I checked with my algorithm on Matlab and it says it converges in 6 steps when I make my initial guess x_0 = 1

Comment: @Wolfy Unless I made an algebraic mistake then you should have $x_2=x_3=x_4=\dots$ and indeed this happens in my calculation (for randomly chosen $b$ and $x_0$).

Comment: Not sure, point being in my question is that since I know gauss-Seidel converges how do we determine if it does converge in a finite number of iterations.

Comment: @Wolfy $G^2=0$ which implies together with the formula for $x_n$ that the method (in this particular case) converges in two iterations. It is easy to see that in general $G^n=0$ implies that $x_n=x_{n+1}=\cdots =x$ *for any initial $x_0$*.